# Using geometry nodes and mesh primitives

Tags: geometry-nodes

Having discovered geometry nodes, I am experimenting with procedural modelling.

I am trying to build  simple object that is a set of stacked cylinders. Can I use Transfer Attribute or Attribute Capture to get the height of the first cylinder and use it as the offset for the second cylinder so that, regardless of changes to the first cylinder, he second always lays on top?

Comment: You've hit on the exact use-case of the _Accumulate Field_ node that's [illustrated in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/accumulate_field.html?highlight=accumulate%20field#stacking-boxes)

Comment: Why not make this the answer?

Comment: Because I _think_ it's been given before, but I'm having trouble finding it :)

Comment: In fact, the description and presentation in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/accumulate_field.html?highlight=accumulate%20field#stacking-boxes) is exactly the answer to this question. So the question would be a "duplicate" with this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is sufficiently answered with the official documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/accumulate_field.html?highlight=accumulate%20field#stacking-boxes